# How to return a processed video stream to the front end?

Tags: python, frontend, video-streaming, backend

I want to get a video stream from a user and draw dots in certain places, but I don't understand how to do it yet.

Originally I wanted to get a video stream from the frontend to the backend, draw dots and return the video back, but now it seems strange.

Comment: This question is quite general. Can you provide more details, e.g. what framework are you using? What is your frontend and your backend? Ideally, you've already tried something that did not work. Then you can provide the code snippet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.